# How to get a formatted DateTimeField value outside a Django template?

Tags: python, django

I declared a DateTimeField in my model.py

```
date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I show that value in my template like this:

```
{{comment.date}}
```

and this is how it's displayed:

```
Feb. 9, 2014, 2:18 p.m.
```

Apparently the django template engine formats the `DateTimeField` 
value automatically because the server returns those kind
of values like this:

```
2014-02-09 14:18:54.721021+00:00
```

But how should I do to return that value preformated from
the server?

I'm making an AJAX call to the server and the date it's naturally 
returned without the format. Since I have my javascript file outside
the template, I can not just do `{{comment.date}}`.

Comment: You mean you are returning *JSON* on a AJAX request?

Comment: yes, and I need to get the date like it's displayed on the template: Feb. 9, 2014, 2:18 p.m.

Comment: You'd have to either alter the Datetime serialization in the JSON response or use the [JavaScript i18n catalog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog) to format the dates on the client side. I've not done either, if I have time I'll figure out some examples.

Comment: thanks @MartijnPieters, I think I'll just return that date formatted from the server. Could you please refer or tell me how can I format a Django DateTimeField? I have searched a lot with no success about how to get a pretty string from a DateTimeField

Answer (score 1):

there may be a few different answers and each one will have it's pros and cons.

I'm coming from the API world, where I can have multiple consumers of the API functions.

in your case you have a backend service which is returning structural data (json), in such a case it is goo do pass data, that will be independent of the consumer.

JSON does not have any standard format for the date, but there is ISO-8601, it is both human readable and structurized and easily parsable on the javascript side e.g. agular.js is parsing it without any additional efforts, moment.js (which is great) and even pure Date are fully capable to read it.

so, imho - go with iso-8601.

there are multiple answers how to add date serialization to json.dump.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it and it didn't look answered so I'm answering this for other users on what I think Martijn wanted.

See Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for datetime strftime. 
Datetime objects can be formatted like the example below which formats 2014-02-09 14:18:54.721021+00:00 into Feb. 9, 2014, 2:18 PM.

```
formatted_datetime_as_string = comment.date.strftime('%b. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p')
```

Then use `formatted_datetime_as_string` in your JSON data.